# add-apt-repository: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

While executing below command

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

I get the following error in command line editor

```
add-apt-repository: command not found
```

Comment: `add-apt-repository` or `apt-add-repository`? Which system?

Comment: @Mathieu `apt-add-repository` is actually a symlink to `add-apt-repository`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the package `software-properties-common` first:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get update
```

Then use `add-apt-repository` to add your PPA.